# Generate non-duplicate list in python

Tags: python, list, python-docx

I am trying to generate a list that contains `anchor` names in `w:hyperlink` elements by looping over all document's elements using the `python-docx` library, with this code:

```py
def get_hyperlinks(docx__document):
    hyperlinks_in_document = list()
    for counter, element in enumerate(docx__document.elements):
        if isinstance(element, Paragraph) and not element.is_heading:
            hyperlinks_in_document.extend(element._element.xpath('//w:hyperlink/@w:anchor'))
    return list(set(hyperlinks_in_document))
```

The above code returns a list with anchors found the issue I'm having is when a text is separated into multiple runs therefore a list "generated from looping into element" can have duplicated names and the output is being like this:

```py
['American', 'Syrian', 'American', 'Syrian', 'American', 'Syrian', 'American', 'Syrian']
```

I tried these codes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) but still with the issue of duplicate or performance of code is affected but this code here:

```py
def get_hyperlinks(docx__document):
    hyperlinks_in_document = list()
    returned_links = list()
    for counter, element in enumerate(docx__document.elements):
        if isinstance(element, Paragraph) and not element.is_heading:
            hyperlinks_in_document.extend(element._element.xpath('//w:hyperlink/@w:anchor'))
            [returned_links.append(element_in_list) for element_in_list in hyperlinks_in_document
             if element_in_list not in returned_links]
    return returned_links
```

solve the issue of duplicate but the performance is affected. any ideas that can help?

Comment: Why can't you use only a `set` and do set union? That will solve the duplication and the performance problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes with the previous code and figured out to switch the final list to set therefore I got non-duplicate items with less time:

```py
def get_hyperlinks(docx__document):    
    hyperlinks, returned_links = list(), set()
    for counter, element in enumerate(docx__document.elements):
        if isinstance(element, Paragraph) and not element.is_heading:
            hyperlinks = element._p.getparent().xpath('.//w:hyperlink')
    hyperlinks = [str(hyperlink.get(qn("w:anchor"))) for hyperlink in hyperlinks]
    returned_links = list(set().union(hyperlinks))
    # [returned_links.append(element_in_list) for element_in_list in hyperlinks
    #          if element_in_list not in returned_links]
    return returned_links
```

*Commented lines show what I did before and the whole answer is the final code.*